# error with jdatechooser cannot find method in java

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I am getting an error that it can't find the method getModel() and I am not sure what to do about this. I am trying to make it so that when a button is clicked, the dob variable is set to the value in the jdatechooser.

```
public Calendar getDOB()
{
return dob;
}    


JDateChooser jdc = new JDateChooser();
JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();

Calendar calendar;

UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
 model.setDate(1990, 8, 24);
 JDatePanelImpl datePanel;
 JDatePickerImpl datePicker;

Person samplePerson = new Person();

btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            samplePerson.setDOB(calendar.getModel().getValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: JCalendar and JDateChooser has no getModel method, what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get the date from the jdatechooser

Comment: Try: `jdc.getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the getModel method on your Calendar instance (which doesn't have a getModel method) instead of on your JDatePanel instance

Comment: JDateChooser  also has no getModel method. See the [javadoc](http://javadox.com/com.toedter/jcalendar/1.4/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html)

Comment: Good call @Jens I didn't check the api for JDateChooser.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind! I got it! The following line worked for me.

```
samplePerson.setDOB(jdc.getCalendar());
```